# Laravel HTTP client PUT request with attachement and basic auth

Tags: php, laravel, httpclient

I was reading the laravel HTTP client documentation on how to send request using PUT request with `attach` and `withBasicAuth`. Below is my code but I'm getting error

```
//validate file input
$data = $request->validate([
            'file' => 'bail|required'
        ]);

$user = auth()->user()->api;

//make request
$results = Http::withBasicAuth($user->api_key, $user->api_secret)
                ->put("/url")
                ->attach('data', file_get_contents($data['file']->getPathName()));
$data = $results->json();

dd($data); //Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response::attach()
```

anyone experienced similar situation? thanks

Comment: `put` will send the request so I would think `attach` needs to be called before `put`

Comment: You are correct attach needs to be called before put and I provide a third argument which is the filename

Comment: Your `$user` variable doesn't contain a user.

Comment: @LobsterBaz it does. it's a relationship to get the api key and secret as basic auth

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to solve the issue

```
$results = Http::withBasicAuth($user->api_key, $user->api_secret)
                ->attach('data', file_get_contents($data['file']->getPathName()), 'filename.txt')
                ->put("/url");
$data = $results->json();
```